# MFC Ribbon crashes in windows 2008

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, mfc, windows-server-2008, ribbon

I have an application that uses the MFC Ribbon. It is developed in Visual Studio 2010. I am facing a strange issue. The app works fine in Windows 7 and windows 2008 R2. However it crashes in windows 2008 when it tries to load the ribbon from resource. The exact line is

> ribbonBar->LoadFromResource(IDR_RIBBON1); //IDR_RIBBON1 is the resource id.

The stack trace is below

```
gui.exe!ATL::CComPtrBase<IXMLDOMDocument>::~CComPtrBase<IXMLDOMDocument>()  Line 162 + 0xa bytes    C++
gui.exe!ATL::CComPtr<IXMLDOMDocument>::~CComPtr<IXMLDOMDocument>()  + 0x11 bytes    C++
gui.exe!ATL::CComQIPtr<IXMLDOMDocument,&_GUID_2933bf81_7b36_11d2_b20e_00c04f983e60>::~CComQIPtr<IXMLDOMDocument,&_GUID_2933bf81_7b36_11d2_b20e_00c04f983e60>()  + 0x11 bytes    C++
gui.exe!ATL::CXMLNode<IXMLDOMDocument>::~CXMLNode<IXMLDOMDocument>()  Line 47 + 0xb bytes   C++
gui.exe!ATL::CXMLDocument::~CXMLDocument()  Line 269 + 0x13 bytes   C++
gui.exe!CXMLParserRoot::~CXMLParserRoot()  Line 423 + 0x43 bytes    C++
gui.exe!CMFCRibbonInfo::Read(unsigned char * lpBuffer=0x013acb14, unsigned int nSize=83851)  Line 703 + 0x15 bytes  C++
gui.exe!CMFCRibbonInfoLoader::LoadFromBuffer(unsigned char * lpBuffer=0x013acb14, unsigned int nSize=83851)  Line 112 + 0x1b bytes  C++
gui.exe!CMFCRibbonInfoLoader::Load(const char * lpszResID=0x000005d8, const char * lpszResType=0x0000001c, HINSTANCE__ * hInstance=0x00400000)  Line 85 + 0x1c bytes    C++
gui.exe!CMFCRibbonBar::LoadFromResource(const char * lpszXMLResID=0x000005d8, const char * lpszResType=0x0000001c, HINSTANCE__ * hInstance=0x00000000)  Line 740 + 0x17 bytes   C++
gui.exe!CMFCRibbonBar::LoadFromResource(unsigned int uiXMLResID=1496, const char * lpszResType=0x0000001c, HINSTANCE__ * hInstance=0x00000000)  Line 731    C++
```

Any suggestions, advice as to how to go about this issue is greatly appreciated. Do, ask if you need more information.

Comment: It isn't very clear what the crash actually looks like.  An access violation in a destructor call is almost always caused by heap corruption.  That corruption wasn't caused by the ribbon control but by code that ran earlier.

Answer (score 3):

I know this answer is years late, but I just ran into your same problem while updating an old MFC application to support the Ribbon.
What needed to be done in order for `LoadResources` to work correctly, was to call `AfxOleInit()` during `InitInstance()` in the App class. I do this before loading the MFC frame.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. Adding a call to AfxOleInit() fixed the issue for me on Windows 10, using VS 2017 too.

Comment: You're the man! It fixed it for me in VS2022 under Win10

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to install redistributable package on deployed machine? It is possible that Windows (Server) 2008 R2 comes with Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable package and Windows Server 2008 not. Also take into account that if you updated Visual Studio to SP1 you should use redistributable package for SP1.

Comment: I have installed the visual C++ 2010 Redistributable x86 on my machine , which is Windows 2008 SP2. The app fails to work.